# Yii2 show item based on NOW() doesn't show the day itself

Tags: mysql, date, yii2, expression

I'm trying to create a 'next in the agenda' item to place on an index page for an application I created with Yii2.

With the function below I retrieve the next item in the database that is 'upcoming' and shown based on the class of the trip and the date. I'm using the NOW() expression.

However, this means the next upcoming item will be shown until it hits the NOW() date, so its not shown anymore on the day itself. Ideally, i should have the upcoming item to show also until the time has passed the $this->time or only show the item after this one the day after NOW().

Anyone any tips how I can achieve this?

```
public function searchANext($params)
{
    $query = Trip::find();
    $time = new Expression('NOW()');
    $query->where(['class' => Trip::CLASS_A])
        ->andWhere(['>=', 'date', $time])
        ->limit(1);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['date' => SORT_ASC]],
        'pagination' => false
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to show 1 record, why are you using `ActiveDataProvider`?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why you are returning an `ActiveDataProvider` when you only want to get a single record, it is unnecessary for this case in my opinion.

Also, you are loading `$params` and validating the model after you create the query, so if the `$params` are not valid you will still get an error and you eventually return `$dataProvider` no matter what the load and validate methods return.

I suggest you make a few changes to your code:

```
public function searchANext($params)
{
    // Try to load $params and validate the model first and return false
    // instead of returning the result of the search.
    if(!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return false;
    }

    // Let's get the currend DateTime. You might need to change this
    // depending on the format of the 'date' field from 'Trip'
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Instead of creating an ActiveDataProvider, you can just get the one
    // record directly and return it.
    $model = Trip::find()
        ->where(['class' => Trip::CLASS_A])
        ->andWhere(['>=', 'date', $now])
        ->orderBy('date ASC')
        ->one();

    return $model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its a good remark. I guess I was a bit hasty and I copied the general search function and edited it. But my skills are still limited at this time so thanks for the explanation. I will check it out asap. thanks !